# Where can I find images for vector chess diagrams?

Tags: notation

Chess diagrams are simple, icon-based images and there's no reason they need to be raster images. I've seen many threads started on this topic throughout the web, always unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

Someone has just posted a collection of tools for creating vector chess diagrams on reddit. You can find them [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/1k6bdx/images_for_vector_chess_diagrams/). If anyone knows of some more resources like this I'd love to hear about them.